# How can I change the version of a gem that one of my gems depends on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to use the [evernote gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/evernote). It relies on the [thrift gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/thrift).

Gemfile

```
gem 'evernote'
```

When I try to use it, I get this error:

```
Thrift::ProtocolException in PagesController#the_lab 
No version identifier, old protocol client?
thrift (0.5.0) lib/thrift/protocol/binary_protocol.rb:122:in `read_message_begin'
thrift (0.5.0) lib/thrift/client.rb:45:in `receive_message'
evernote (0.9.0) vendor/gen-rb/evernote/edam/note_store.rb:97:in `recv_listNotebooks'
```

There is a [newer version of the thrift gem available](http://rubygems.org/gems/thrift/versions/0.6.0), which could potentially fix the problem. When I try to install it, I get this error:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'evernote'
gem 'thrift', "~> 0.6.0"
```

Console:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
You have requested:
  thrift ~> 0.6.0

The bundle currently has thrift locked at 0.5.0.
Try running `bundle update thrift`

$ bundle update thrift
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "thrift":
  In Gemfile:
    evernote depends on
      thrift (~> 0.5.0)

    thrift (0.6.0)
```

Is there a way I can change the version of thrift that evernote relies on?

Comment: Incidentally, that error `No version identifier, old protocol client?` is from Thrift and indicates that it could not parse the response according to the IDL it had for the indicated object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You 'could' fork the evernote gem, update it to use the appropriate version of thrift and then use that in your app?

Gemfile

```
gem 'evernote', :git => "https://github.com/your_username/evernote.git
```

Then send cgs a pull request if relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Remove the reference to thrift in you Gemfile
2. Run `bundle update evernote`

It seems the latest version of evernote doesn't depend on a specific version of thrift, so that should solve your issue. If not, try having both evernote and thrift in your Gemfile and updating both (which should result in your having the latest versions of both gems).

Comment: Is the latest version of evernote 0.9.0? That's what it seems to indicate on this page - http://rubygems.org/gems/evernote. That's what I'm using as well, as you can see from this line in the second code block above:evernote (0.9.0) vendor/gen-rb/evernote/edam/note_store.rb:97:in `recv_listNotebooks'

Comment: Yes, 0.9.0 seems to be the latest version. However, the source at https://github.com/cgs/evernote doesn't indicate a specific version dependency. Maybe try using the HEAD branch in your Gemfile with `gem 'evernote', :git => "https://github.com/cgs/evernote.git"`

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your help. Tried your suggestion, unfortunately the exact same error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Fork evernote gem & edit your gemfile to refer to that.
Edit .gemspec of your forked evernote gem to match the version of thrift.